# CSS Media Query Orientation Change not working PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, css, cordova, orientation, media-queries

when using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="css/i-hoch.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 960px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="css/i-quer.css">
```

on iPhone Mobile Safari the CSS is changed when device is rotated.

The same Page does not load the different CSS when this code is used within the PhoneGap Framework (0.9.5.1). We also had issues with the

```
<meta name="viewport"
```

which could be fixed but orientation problems remain.
Any hints how to solve this issue are appreciated. Thanks in advance - Alex

Answer (score 0):

@alex, may be first you have check you css file link with firebug & if the path is correct then
write  like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="css/i-hoch.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="css/i-quer.css">
```

may be that's helpful