# css media queries not working while using PhoneGap

Tags: ios, css, cordova

I am developing an iPhone/iPad app using PhoneGap and js/css3, and have recently started using the iPad's larger screen size to make specific adjustments to my layout.
I added an iPhone only section in my css with

`@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {`

and an iPad only section with

`@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) {`

and they seemed to work fine on my desktop when I was debugging (using chrome, both in win and mac, and safari in mac).
When I built my app in xCode, and ran it on the device, it seems as though all the rules inside those sections are ignored completely, and my layout is all wrong.

Is there some trick I should use, in order to make this work for me?

Answer (score 2):

It is important that you add the viewport to the head of your html document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Also see:
[CSS Media Query Orientation Change not working PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533481/css-media-query-orientation-change-not-working-phonegap)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-width: 481px) {
```

for your iPad only section and get back to me?